# Indexing numpy array with another numpy array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

Suppose I have

```
a = array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4]])
```

and

```
b = array([1,1])
```

I'd like to use b in index a, that is to do a[b] and get 4 instead of [[3, 4], [3, 4]]

I can probably do

```
a[tuple(b)]
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is a problem. why you think a[tuple(b)] is bad?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

According the [NumPy tutorial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#indexing-with-arrays-of-indices), the correct way to do it is:

```py
a[tuple(b)]
```

Answer (score 22):

Suppose you want to access a subvector of `a` with n index pairs stored in `b`like so:

```
b = array([[0, 0],
       ...
       [1, 1]])
```

This can be done as follows:

```
a[b[:,0], b[:,1]]
```

For a single pair index vector this changes to `a[b[0],b[1]]`, but I guess the `tuple` approach is easier to read and hence preferable.

Comment: But which is faster I wonder?  Wouldn't tuple() create a copy whereas the views above would not?

Answer (score 2):

The above is correct. However, if you see an error like:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

You may have your index array in floating type. Change it to something like this:

```
arr[tuple(a.astype(int))]
```