# Selecting Array Values With A Separate Array of Indices

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I am attempting to index a stacked 3-D Numpy array (named `stack`) by a group of 2-D indices contained inside of a separate Numpy array (named `piece`). The separate array contains several groups of 2-D index pairs. Inspection of these indices at the first entry of the array is as follows:

```
[[0 1]
 [1 0]
 [0 0]
 [1 1]
 [2 0]
 [0 2]
 [2 1]
 [1 2]]
```

The dimensions of the stacked 3-D array are `(1228, 2606, 14)`, which was created by stacking multiple 2-D arrays to ultimately inspect values along common index value pairs. I've tried indexing stack by piece in several methods, both of which have not produced the desired result:

1. extraction = stack[tuple(piece), :]
2. extraction = stack[piece, :]

Attempt #1 was derived from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508352/indexing-numpy-array-with-another-numpy-array). In both instances, the shape of extraction yields `(8, 2, 2606, 14)` as opposed to an array that contains 112 values across the 8 provided index pairs. Any insight as to where corrections can be made is appreciated!

Comment: `stack[piece[:,0], piece[:,1]]`?

Comment: That would do it, thanks!